# Docker jupyter notebook uses container id as ip, localhost

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to run jupyter notebook in Docker based on python 3. The notebook starts but displays the container id as ip. It does work if I change it to 'localhost:' in the browser after opening the link.

How to make it work properly and show localhost: in the url? /os: Ubuntu 18.04/

EDIT: I have tried the [jupyter/minimal-notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/minimal-notebook) and that works, shows localhost, but it is based on ubuntu 18.04, which is not compatible with some packages I want to use later in the notebooks.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get -y update \
&& apt-get upgrade -y \
&& apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    vim \
    xterm
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir jupyter numpy matplotlib
# Add Tini. Tini operates as a process subreaper for jupyter. This prevents
# kernel crashes.
ENV TINI_VERSION v0.6.0
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /usr/bin/tini
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tini", "--"]

EXPOSE 8888
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--allow-root"]
```

Running it after build

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8888:8888 -v "$PWD":/home/work e4b37115446d
```

Output:

```
[I 11:48:12.580 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 11:48:12.826 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /
[I 11:48:12.826 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 11:48:12.826 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 11:48:12.826 NotebookApp] http://3b906c2d97f3:8888/?token=06d43a78966a7b7e5fd04318183fa3e7af5bca7542477d31
[I 11:48:12.826 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 11:48:12.827 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time, to login with a token:
        http://3b906c2d97f3:8888/?token=06d43a78966a7b7e5fd04318183fa3e7af5bca7542477d31&token=06d43a78966a7b7e5fd04318183fa3e7af5bca7542477d31
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with docker but isn't the error explicit in what you should follow up? Did you do that?

Comment: thanks, edited the question now with what I have tried also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **`--hostname`** flag when you run the container.  If you leave this empty it defaults to the container name.

```
docker run --rm  -it -p 8888:8888 --hostname localhost jup
```

When run:

```
[I 14:58:32.508 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 14:58:32.508 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=0e59cd9003b843f529b9bc6e7b39921001ddfdb253c029e9
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. Minor comment, use `hostname: localhost` if you use a `docker-compose.yml` file.